# Using EE Proform tag inside Javascript - Not working

Tags: javascript

I've got protect_javascript set to no, here's what I'm trying to do...I'm trying to insert a proform form (blog subscribe) after the 2nd paragraph in every blog post.  I've got this:

```
<script>
 $( ".blogbody p:nth-child(3)" ).after( "{exp:proform:simple form='blog_subscribe' thank_you_url='/page/thank-you-for-signing-up'}" );
 </script>
```

However, it renders immediately in the footer (where the script is) and breaks the javascript.  Anyone have a clue how to fix this?

Comment: When you view source is the script rendered as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work because you're rendering an EE form with the DOM - EE needs to parse those {exp:..} tags in order to generate an HTML form that will work. You'd be better off generating the form  in the EE template and hiding/showing it using javascript/css.

Comment: I'm not trying to hide/show it.  I'm trying to insert it after the third paragraph tag found.  It's dynamic content so I can't do it via the source.  Are you talking about generating the form and using jquery to append it afterwards?

Comment: Ahh, thanks, that worked.  I generated the form and appended it to a div I inserted where I needed it.

Comment: Yay! Glad you got it working